# Scapy - random trailer after a packet

Tags: scapy, trailing

I am running `sacpy 2.4` in `Ubuntu 16.04`. I have found on basic packets ( `Eth/IP/UDP` or `Eth/IP/TCP`) `wireshark` often flags a failed frame check sequence.

Upon investigation I found that the "broken packets" all have trailing data behind the `UDP` or `TCP` payload. The trailing data is interpreted by `wireshark` as FCS and the check fails.

How can i stop the random trailing data from being attached to the packet. It looks like some memory leak, since the trailer contains readable stings, "desktop/IBus/" for example.

[image: <code>Wireshark</code> screenshot]

I have not come across the problem in a `Centos` or `Windows`, but might it be OS or interface card related. Any ideas?

The code used to reproduce the problem:

```
data=Raw(load="A string of data to fill min packet size")
sendp(Ether()/IP(dst="172.16.63.96")/UDP(sport=4123, dport=5432)/data)
```

[image: <code>Wireshark</code> capture of sent packet on origination PC]

From `Scapy` I wrote a `pcap` file containing the generated packets, when inspecting the `pcap` file with `Wireshark`, the packets are good.  If I then play the 'pcap' file out and capture those packets, trailing data appear. I played the `pcap` file using `Scapy` as well as `tcpreplay`. In both cases random trailing data appears. It looks more like a `Ubuntu` or driver issue.

Comment: Can you include example Python code showing how you made the packets?

Comment: I have added the code snip it and another screenshot.  I have not been able to reproduce this on a Windows or Centos OS

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but with Tcpreplay. I downgraded the kernel on my Ubuntu server to 4.15.0-23-generic and this resolved the problem. Just adding this in case anyone with the Tcpreplay issue comes across this post.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found on scapy’s gitter:

[image: Screenshot]

(Edit: it might not cover all versions, but it’s a Linux bug)

It’s a Linux bug

Comment: Im running 4.4.0-133, but assume it is a Linux issue

Comment: I tested this and it works using 4.15.0-23-generic and is broken at 4.15.0-34-generic.